# How to fix photo changeing slideshow in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I did slideshow in Wordpress by php jQuery It basically works like this: 
In Posts I made custom fields with names "sliderPhotoImg1", "sliderPhotoImg2" etc. by php it's taking all photos from custom fields and put inside  as

After this by jQuery I do slideshow, It's easy and it\s works only for one post, but if I have slideshow in every post then is not working for every div $("#Slider-") but index of img that should be displayed jump from post to post.

You can find a problem at www.acroart.pl

```
<div id="Slider-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<?php 
$dot = (int)get_post_meta($post->ID, "dots", true); 

for($i = 0; $i< $dot; $i++){
if($i <= $dot){
    echo '<div><img src="';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "sliderPhotoImg".($i+1), true);
    echo '"></div>';
}
}                               
?>

</div>
<script>
$( "#Slider-<?php the_ID();?> > div:gt(0)" ).hide();
setInterval( function () {
    $( "#Slider-<?php the_ID();?> > div:first" )
        .fadeOut( 1000 )
        .next()
        .fadeIn( 1000 )
        .end()
        .appendTo( "#Slider-<?php the_ID();?>");
    }, 3000 );
    $("#Slider-<?php the_ID();?> > div > img").css({
        "position": "relative",
        "width": "600px",
        "height": "400px"
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added **echo** to the php code inside the jquery, try this and tell us

```
<div id="Slider-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<?php 
$dot = (int)get_post_meta($post->ID, "dots", true); 

for($i = 0; $i< $dot; $i++){
if($i <= $dot){
    echo '<div><img src="';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "sliderPhotoImg".($i+1), true);
    echo '"></div>';
}
}                               
?>

</div>
<script>
$( "#Slider-<?php echo the_ID();?> > div:gt(0)" ).hide();
setInterval( function () {
    $( "#Slider-<?php echo the_ID();?> > div:first" )
        .fadeOut( 1000 )
        .next()
        .fadeIn( 1000 )
        .end()
        .appendTo( "#Slider-<?php the_ID();?>");
    }, 3000 );
    $("#Slider-<?php the_ID();?> > div > img").css({
        "position": "relative",
        "width": "600px",
        "height": "400px"
});
</script>
```

Comment: It Helps, Thank You, How can I add dots?